# Gorm retrive different UUID value from that in the database - MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

Model

```
type Invoice struct {
    ID                uint           `gorm:"primarykey" json:"-"`
    UID               uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;uniqueIndex:idx_UniqueID" json:"id"`
}
```

On database value dispalayed as flowws

[image]

But When I retriving data from database I get different values from those in db
[image]

Is there something wrong on model creation?

handler

```
func GetInvoices(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    invoices := []responses.Invoice{}
    var invoicesCount int64

    page, pageSize, searchString, orderBy := handles.Pages(c)
    switch orderBy {
    case "customer_name":
        orderBy = "CustomerName"
    case "currency_id":
        orderBy = "ForeignCurrenycID"
    default:
        orderBy = "ID"
    }

    if err := database.DB.Model(&models.Invoice{}).Select("ID").Where("InvNumber like ? or CustomerName like ? or Tax_Number like ? or Registration like ? or Description like ?", searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString).Count(&invoicesCount).Error; err != nil {
        logs.ErrorLogger.Println(err.Error())
        return c.Status(400).JSON(fiber.Map{"msg": err.Error()})
    }

    if err := database.DB.Scopes(handles.Paginate(c)).Order(orderBy).Find(&invoices).Where("InvNumber like ? or CustomerName like ? or Tax_Number like ? or Registration like ? or Description like ?", searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString).Error; err != nil {
        logs.ErrorLogger.Println(err.Error())
        return c.Status(400).JSON(fiber.Map{"msg": err.Error()})
    }
    for _, inv := range invoices{
        fmt.Println(inv.UID)
    }
    totalPages := math.Ceil(float64(invoicesCount) / float64(pageSize))

    return c.Status(200).JSON(fiber.Map{"page": page, "pageSize": pageSize, "totalPages": totalPages, "totalItems": invoicesCount, "data": &invoices})
}
```

Comment: No idea about GO but this looke like a big-enddian/little-endian issue, the byte order for the first two segements is reversed

Comment: What query are you running in SSMS to get that result?  What is the table DDL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Even if I query one entry still It's uuid is reversed. If you look on the UID the chars are reversed but same chars. What make them reversed?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ```Select * from Invoice order by I'd offset 0 row fetch next 10 rows only```

Comment: This is not a GORM issue, is more from MSSQL and google uuid lib, I'm having same issue, I've looked at Denissen custom UUID implementation and he implements a "reverse" method: https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/ed0f62060df11d7cf555612aff3b66bbabc374d3/uniqueidentifier.go#L55

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, my DBA found a quick-fix converting to NVARCHAR the ID in the GORM Select method, you could use:

```
// ...
    if err := database.DB.Model(&models.Invoice{}).Select("CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), ID) as ID").Where("InvNumber like ? or CustomerName like ? or Tax_Number like ? or Registration like ? or Description like ?", searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString).Count(&invoicesCount).Error; err != nil {
        logs.ErrorLogger.Println(err.Error())
        return c.Status(400).JSON(fiber.Map{"msg": err.Error()})
    }
// ...
```

I know this is not the best way, but it works  ¯\*(ツ)*/¯